# Reading a change in session storage from react continuously

Tags: reactjs, session, react-redux

what is the best approach to identify the session storage value change from react application and based on which the state should be updated?

instead of continuous looping and checking is there any better way to achieve this without losing performance.

Answer (score 0):

If a value in your storage changes it propagates automatically to the components who are using this value. This is because the components re-renders when a new value is passed on them.

For example: if you have a value like this `session.isAuthenticated` in your storage and that value is being used by `App` component to show or not the `Logout` button when you call the `logout` action this will modify the value so the `Logout` button won't be shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no pure Javascript solution for your problem since in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API), it clearly states:

> The StorageEvent is fired whenever a change is made to the Storage object (note that this event is not fired for sessionStorage changes). This won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access the same storage objects.

Assuming your app is purely in React, and no update to sessionStorage is done outside the React parts, please considering following dirty options:

1.Let the reducers do the jobs: reducer receives action with full data, and before updating state, it updates sessionStorage first. Example:

```
const someReducer = (state, { type, payload}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ... 
        case 'UPDATE_SESSIONSTORAGE_AND_STATE':
            sessionStorage.setItem('itemName', state.payload);
            ... // and do normal state-updating job here
        ...
    }
}
```

2.Use [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/): pass data to an action e.g. `UPDATE_SESSIONSTORAGE` and let a saga handles the storage update. Then that saga can fire another action e.g. `UPDATE_STATE` to send same data to corresponding reducer.